# Split table in 2 or more pages using table* and tabularx

Tags: tables, tabularx

I need to put this large table distributed in more than one page. As she has a lot columns also, I could only do fit all columns on the page using tabularx and resizebox.

A part of the table is as follows, have more than 30 ids:

```
\begin{table*}[p]\small
\caption{Lista completa de regras elencadas da literatura}\label{tab:r}\centering
\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{>{\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{W}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{ %
    \begin{tabularx}{\textheight}{p{1cm}|p{1.5cm}|p{1.5cm}|p{1.5cm}|p{2cm}|p{2cm}|p{2cm}|p{2cm}|p{2cm}|p{2cm}|p{2.5cm}}
        Ids & Classificação na literatura & (Alsmadi et. Al, 2011)\cite{Alsmadi2011} & (Badoni et. Al, 2014)\cite{Badoni2014} & (Deris et. Al, 1999)\cite{Deris1999} & (Innet et. Al, 2007\cite{Innet2007
        }) & (Khonggamnerd et. Al, 2009)\cite{khonggamnerd2009improv} & (Nuntasen et. Al, 2007)\cite{Nuntasen2007} & (Pongcharoen et. Al, 2008)\cite{Pongcharoen2008} & (Babaei et. Al, 2014)\cite{Babaei2014} & (Pillay, 2014)\cite{Pillay2014} \\ \hline
        1 & Hard & Professores não podem ministrar aulas simultâneas. Nenhum professor pode dar uma ou mais aulas simultaneamente. &  &  & Não é permitido que professores ministrem duas aulas no mesmo período e dia. & Professores não são permitidos ministrar aulas diferentes no mesmo período e dia. & Professores não são permitidos ministrar aulas diferentes no mesmo período e dia. & Professores podem minitrar aulas em apenas um período por vez. & Um professor pode ministrar apenas uma aula em uma sala de aula em um período. & Um professor não deve ser agendado mais de uma vez durante o mesmo período. \\ \hline
        2 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & Um professor não pode estar em duas salas de aula no mesmo período. &  \\ \hline
\end{tabularx}}
\end{table*}
```

Comment: Welcome! That's an interesting story. Did you want to ask something?

Comment: Which document class do you use? What are the dimensions of the page and of the text block?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks for try help me :). O solve my problem in other way... I save my table in pdf format, so put like this :

```
\begin{table*}[th]
\caption{caption hehehe}\centering
\resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{ %            
    \begin{tabular}{c}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.85\textwidth]{fig/rules.pdf}
    \end{tabular}}
\end{table*}
```